# CakePHP daysAsSql results in wrong condition

Tags: php, cakephp, datetime

I'm in the middle of enabling timezone-support for an app of mine. Internally, we're saving every date `Europe/Vienna` timezone-based.

Now I want to enable timezone-support on user level with little help of the awesome CakePHP `Config.timezone` feature.

So, when a user logs in, I write the user-timezone to Config.timezone and everything's up and running correctly.

Now, let's think of the following scenario:

I have some records in the database, like this one:

```
-- created: 2014-03-17 09:00:00 // Austrian time!
```

So the mentioned record in the database is displayed correctly with `CakeTime::format()` (currently 4 hours difference between Austria and Brasil):

```
 -- created: 2014-03-17 05:00:00 // Brasilian time!
```

Users now can export some of the records from the database with a datepicker. let's think of the same user, based in Brasil, who wants to export some records. (s)he chooses 2014-03-17 as date and assumes to receive all records in his/her timezone.

Currently, i'm using the following query:

```
// from, to = 2014-03-17
$records = $this->find('all', ['conditions' => [CakeTime::daysAsSql($from, $to, 'Object.created')]]);
```

Unfortunately, `CakeTime::daysAsSql`returns the following condition:

```
(Object.created >= '2014-03-16 00:00:00') AND (Object.created <= '2014-03-16 23:59:59')
```

Although I can understand the underlying change (because as a first step, the given from/to-value is internally translated to brasilian time and then cut in half to only receive the date-part (without regard of the time part), the mentioned method returns a wrong condition.

as far as i'm understanding the timezone-problem, shouldn't the final condition for the given use case above be this one:

```
(Object.created >= '2014-03-16 20:00:00') AND (Object.created <= '2014-03-17 19:59:59')
```

So, am I using the wrong CakePHP-function, or do I have a misconception here?

Comment: Always save everything as UTC.

Comment: thx David. but we have a really big project here, where we started to save all records in viennese-timezone some years ago. i would totally go the utc-way in my next project, but i thought that caketime-helper would solve this offset-problem correctly.

Comment: I created a pull request couple of minutes ago. Maybe it clarifies the issue a little bit better. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/3041